# Django Patterns: One-To-One Field, Auto Create

Tags: python, django

Is there a good way, or a common pattern to automatically create `one-to-one` fields that do not yet exist? Conceptually, I want my `OneToOneField` to work like a `get_or_create` call. For example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="foo", unique=True)

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def foo(self):
        """
        This is what I want to achieve conceptually.
        """
        foo, created = Foo.objects.get_or_create(...)
        return foo

    ...

user.foo() # if none, will create.
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can easily use a `post_save` signal on `User` to create a related `Foo`, [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signals/)

Comment: Is this the preferred way to do this? I’d prefer to always create if one doesn’t exist, even if this is unlikely to happen.

Comment: If you want to always create one, I believe this is the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prevent you from unnecessarily hitting the database every time you access the property

```
class Details(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='d', unique=True) # change related name to 'd' so 'user.details' could be used as the computed property's name

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def details(self):
        try:
             return self.d
        except Details.DoesNotExist as e:
             return Details.objects.create(user=self)
    ...

user.details # if none, will create.
```

Comment: A shorter way would be using `return Details.objects.get_or_create(user=self)` instead of  this try/except block.

Comment: @partizaans yeah, but your example hits the database correct?

Comment: @partizaans As mentioned in the answer, you'll be hitting the database every time you call that property.

Comment: @aroooo My bad mistake. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can override save method of User model.

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    is_new = self.pk is None  # check if object is new to be saved
    super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
    Foo.objects.create(user=self) if is_new else None
```